# How to access content of declared Variable in python in my POSTGRES sql query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am just getting my hand dirty with python, hence my question might look silly. Yeah, I have the following code as per of a class. The declared variable in python was to accepted input from the user and then cross checked the content of the variable with an POSTGRES SQL statement.
See the code below;

```
def view_user(self):
    self.contact_modify = input('Please enter name to modify : ')
    contact_modify = self.contact_modify
    try:
        con = self.db_conn()
        print('We are connected to the db now')
    except:
        print('I can not find your database connection here')

    try:
        print(contact_modify) # to check the content of the variable
        con.execute("SELECT * FROM phone WHERE address_name = :'contact_modify'")
        print(contact_modify) # To check the contents of the variable
        while True:
            row = con.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                break
            print(row[1],row[2],row[3])
    except:
        print("Error displaying your data")
```

I can get the content of the declared variable named 'contact_modify' at all line of code where I print it, but my POSTGRES SQL is not getting the content hence my EXCEPT part of the code is been execute. I am on POSGRES-9.3 and python 3.4 on 64 Windows10 Machine.

Comment: Well you're very cleverly hiding the problem by catching all exceptions and printing a useless nonspecific message instead. *Remove* that blank except block and let Python print the actual exception.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, your observation was almost the solution I had been sought after for more than 3 days now. I am still interesting in catching any error at that stage, can you guide me to the proper thing to do at that stage. Thanks once again.

Comment: the actual error is as follow;     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/datafolder/python lesson/testDB.py", line 52, in <module>
    view.view_user()
  File "E:/datafolder/python lesson/testDB.py", line 37, in view_user
    con.execute("SELECT * FROM phone WHERE address_name = :'contact_modify'")
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM phone WHERE address_name = :'contact_modify'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass your variable manually, like this:

```
conn.execute("SELECT foo FROM table where bar = '%s'" % var)
```

Also, you can use .format() method.

Comment: Thanks, the script work like a charm, after remove the try and except part. I am still interesting in catching the error

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
  con.execute("""SELECT * FROM phone WHERE address_name ='%s';"""%(contact_modify))
```

If not work then do as  @**Daniel Roseman** said. remove `try and except` and see the actual error.

Comment: Thanks, the script work like a charm, after remove the try and except part.